# Tkinter button not clicking until I switch windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I am following a Tkinter tutorial and I have a very basic GUI built. When I run it, the GUI opens and everything is fine, except the button is not immediately clickable. The only way I can get it to click is if I switch to a full screen window and back to the GUI. Below is the code I am using, along with a screenshot. Does anyone know why this is happening? If it does not make enough sense I can upload a video. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#ff9a7f')
frame.place(relwidth=2, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(root, text='Test Button')
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Tkinter GUI]

Comment: This works for me. What ver of `python` are you running?

Comment: I think this is a known bug on OSX.